# How to return the list<class> in c#?

Tags: c#, json, list

I tried to return the List from a method. But I got only the last iterate data in the list. Where do I made a mistake? It overwrites the data at every loop in the list.

```
 public class ProjectData
 {
     public string name { get; set; }
     public string id { get; set; }
     public string web_url { get; set; }
 }

 public static List<ProjectData> GetProjectList()
 {
     int pageCount = 0;
     bool check = true;
     List<ProjectData> copy = new List<ProjectData>();
     List<ProjectData> projectData = new List<ProjectData>();

     while (check)
     {
         ProjectData NewProjectData = new ProjectData();
         pageCount = pageCount + 1;
         string userURL = "http://gitlab.company.com/api/v3/groups/450/projects?private_token=token&per_page=100&page=" + pageCount;
         HttpWebRequest requestforuser = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(userURL);
         HttpWebResponse responseforuser = requestforuser.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
         using (Stream responseStream = responseforuser.GetResponseStream())
         {
             StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
             var JSONString = reader.ReadToEnd();
             projectData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ProjectData>>(JSONString);
             if (JSONString == "[]")
             {
                 check = false;
                 break;
             }
         }
         copy = projectData.ToList();
     }
     return copy;
 }
```

I know there are more that 300 data available to fill in the list. I checked it by using break point. In that, I found all the data are fetching correctly.But it was not copied to the `copy<>`list. Each and every time It is being overwritten in the `copy<>` list. How do I prevent the over writing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In each iteration you are overwriting the values of `copy` with the current value in the `projectData` and the last value only will get returned. actually `projectData` and `copy` are of the same type ie, `List<ProjectData>` so you need not convert them again as a List by using `.ToList()`. In short, you have to use like this :

```
copy.AddRange(projectData);
```

Instead for this `copy = projectData.ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

Replace `copy = projectData.ToList();` 
with `copy.Add(projectData.ToList());`

Comment: Actually this is wrong you can't add a `List<ProjectData>` using `Add` method, you have to use `AddRange` instead. One more thing `projectData` is already a List you need not to call `.ToList()` again

Comment: I got the desired output by replace the line `copy = projectData.ToList();` by `copy.AddRange(projectData);`